# Find integer solutions equation of ${ x }_{ 1 }^{ 4 }+{ { x }_{ 2 }^{ 4 }+ }{ x }_{ 3 }^{ 4 }+...+{ x }_{ 14 }^{ 4 }=1599 $

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

I tried to solve this equation,but can't end up

> $${ x }_{ 1 }^{ 4 }+{ { x }_{ 2 }^{ 4 }+ }{ x }_{ 3 }^{ 4 }+...+{ x }_{ 14 }^{ 4 }=1599$$

**My work**:  Consider arbitrary  $x_{ i }=2k,\quad \forall i\in \{ 1,2,\dots ,14\} $ is even number. Then  $${ x }_{ i }^{ 4 }=16k\equiv 0 \pmod{16}$$ now consider  $x_{ i }=2k-1\quad \forall i\in \{ 1,2,\dots 14\}$  is odd number then ${ x }_{ i }^{ 4 }-1$ will be even, and by fractionalizing it we will  get $$\\ \\ { x }_{ i }^{ 4 }-1=\left( { x }_{ i }-1 \right) \left( { x }_{ i }+1 \right) \left( { x }_{ i }^{ 2 }+1 \right) $$ 
hence 
\begin{align}
{ \left( 2k-1 \right)  }^{ 4 }-1 &=\left( \left( 2k-1 \right) ^{ 2 }-1 \right) \left( \left( 2k-1 \right) ^{ 2 }+1 \right) =\left( 2k-1-1 \right) \left( 2k-1+1 \right) \left( \left( 2k-1 \right) ^{ 2 }+1 \right) \\ 
& \hspace{10mm} =\left( 2k-2 \right) \left( 2k \right) \left( 4{ k }^{ 2 }-4k+2 \right) =16\left( k-1 \right) \left( k \right) \left( { k }^{ 2 }-k+0.5 \right) 
\end{align}
both side are even and are divided to $16$ , so $$\\ { x }_{ i }^{ 4 }\equiv 1 \pmod{16} $$

i am stack here,how proceed? Any hints please.

P.S. I'm also interested about another solution, or best ideas.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does this equation come from? Since all the terms are nonnegative and $1599^{1/4} < 7$, you can at least brute-force it if nothing more clever comes up.

Comment: @anomaly,this question is  in list of my summer mathhomework questions,${ 1599 }^{ 1/4 }<7\\ \\ $ how did you get it?

Comment: $5^4 = 625,$ $6^4 = 1296,$ but $7^4 = 2401.$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

there are no integer solutions. A fourth power is either $0$ or $1 \pmod {16},$ and $1599 \equiv 15 \pmod {16}.$ You are given only fourteen fourth powers, not fifteen, so you cannot do it.

Note that it is proved that 19 fourth powers are always enough, this is the notation $g(4) = 19$ in Waring's problem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem  where they point out that $79$ requires 19 fourth powers; $$16 + 16 + 16 + 16 + 1 + 1 + 1  + 1 + 1 + 1  + 1 + 1 + 1  + 1 + 1 + 1  + 1 + 1 + 1 =79$$

Comment: Absolute logic. Great....